# data.table update last element in group based on condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with 3 columns: id, time and status. For each id, I want to find the record with the maximum time - then if for that record, the status is true, I want to set it to false if the time is > 7 (for example). I am doing it in the following manner.

```
x <- data.table(id=c(1,1,2,2),time=c(5,6,7,8),status=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))
setkey(x,id,time)
y <- x[,.SD[.N],by=id]
x[y,status:=status & time > 7]
```

I have a lot of data I am working with and would like to speed up this operation. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is `time` unique within `id` (so there is a "record with the maximum time")?

Comment: Personally, I like your approach better than the answers'. I would change it to `y = x[, .SD[.N, .(time, status)], by=id][time > 7 & status]; x[y, status := FALSE]`, though. (The `.(time,status)` thing is only useful if you have other vars that aren't needed for the condition.)

Comment: Yes, time is unique within id, so there will be a record with the maximum time.

Answer (score 9):

One `data.table` approach is

```
x[ x[order(time), .I[.N], by=id]$V1 , status := ifelse(time > 7, FALSE, TRUE)]

> x
#   id time status
#1:  1    5  FALSE
#2:  1    6   TRUE
#3:  2    7  FALSE
#4:  2    8  FALSE
```

as `x[order(time), .I[.N], by=id]$V1` gives us the row index of the maximum `time` for each group (`id`)

And, borrowing from @Floo0's answer we can simplify it slightly to

```
x[ x[order(time), .I[.N], by=id]$V1 , status := status * time <= 7]
```

**Speed Comparison**

A speed test of the various answers (and keeping the keys on the data)

```
set.seed(123)
x <- data.table(id=c(rep(seq(1:10000), each=10)),
                time=c(rep(seq(1:10000), 10)),
                status=c(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10000*10, replace=T)))
setkey(x,id,time)
x1 <- copy(x); x2 <- copy(x); x3 <- copy(x); x4 <- copy(x); x5 <- copy(x); x6 <- copy(x)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(

    Symbolix = {x1[ x1[order(time), .I[.N], by=id]$V1 , status := status * time < 7 ] },

    Floo0_1 = {x2[,status := c(.SD[-.N, status], .SD[.N, status * time > 7]), by=id]},

    Floo0_2 = {x3[x3[,.N, by=id][,cumsum(N)], status := status * time > 7]},

    Original = { 
                y <- x4[,.SD[.N],by=id]
                x4[y,status:=status & time > 7]
               },

    Frank = {
             y <- x5[, .SD[.N, .(time, status)], by=id][time > 7 & status]
             x5[y, status := FALSE]
             },

    thelatemail = {x6[ x6[,.I==.I[which.max(time)], by=id]$V1 & time > 7, status := FALSE]}
)

Unit: milliseconds
        expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
    Symbolix    5.419768    5.857477    6.514111    6.222118    6.936000   11.284580   100 a  
     Floo0_1 4550.314775 4710.679867 4787.086279 4776.794072 4850.334011 5097.136148   100   c
     Floo0_2    1.653419    1.792378    1.945203    1.881609    2.014325    4.096006   100 a  
    Original   10.052947   10.986294   12.541595   11.431182   12.391287   89.494783   100 a  
       Frank 4609.115061 4697.687642 4743.886186 4735.086113 4785.212543 4932.270602   100  b 
 thelatemail   10.300864   11.594972   12.421889   12.315852   12.984146   17.630736   100 a
```

Comment: thanks for the comparison, but i think it needs two improvements: 1st comparing on a 4x3 data.table is very boring. Please go for a 1mio x 3 table or so to really compare speedup. Second: you did not key the data-tables... why? In the original question there were keyed. Most solutions use `by` o it could make a huge difference.

Comment: @Floo0 - 1: good point, I'll run a larger test in a bit. 2: I took the original `setkey` to be part of the solution, not the question. But, I agree it will be good to see what happens if the key is set on all the solutions.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this got a down vote...?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you kept the tiny benchmark up so long. (It's not my vote.)

Comment: Yeah, your new benchmark is fine -- no need for the "more appropriate" snark. I've added mine since I was in the middle of making it already. I set `times=1` so that the modification to `X` from the previous iteration doesn't carry over somehow; it's pretty common.

Comment: @Frank wasn't meant to be 'snarky' to any other poster, I accept my original wasn't really an appropriate test :-). I was also wondering what impact the by-reference update does to `x` in the benchmark, but wasn't sure how to test it.

Comment: @Symbolix, thanks for the speed comparison. Good to see the fastest is getting about an order of magnitude improvement over the original!

Answer (score 9):

```
x[x[,.N, by=id][,cumsum(N)], status := status * time <=7]
```

If i am not mistaken, this is no join as `x[,.N, by=id][,cumsum(N)]` returns the row-indices of the last elements per group.

**Update:**
After seeing the speed comparison this one seems the winner and should be listed first

This was my initial attempt which turns out to be the slowest of all suggested solutions

```
x[,status := c(.SD[-.N, status], .SD[.N, status * time <=7]), by=id]
```

Comment: One thing that always amazes me is how flexible `data.table` is that allows multiple solutions!

Comment: do you have your inequality expression the wrong way round?

Comment: This is great, exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 6):

Another attempt:

```
x[ x[,.I==.I[which.max(time)], by=id]$V1 & time > 7, status := FALSE]
x

#   id time status
#1:  1    5  FALSE
#2:  1    6   TRUE
#3:  2    7  FALSE
#4:  2    8  FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way, similar to the OP's:

```
y = unique(x[,c("id","time"), with=FALSE], by="id", fromLast=TRUE)
x[y[time > 7], status := FALSE]
```

Here's another benchmark:

```
n_id = 1e3; n_col = 100; n_draw  = 5

set.seed(1)
X = data.table(id = 1:n_id)[, .(
    time    = sample(10,n_draw), 
    status  = sample(c(T,F), n_draw, replace=TRUE)
), by=id][, paste0("V",1:n_col) := 0]
setkey(X,id,time)

X1 = copy(X); X2 = copy(X); X3 = copy(X); X4 = copy(X)
X5 = copy(X); X6 = copy(X); X7 = copy(X); X8 = copy(X)

library(microbenchmark)
library(multcomp)

microbenchmark(
unique = {
    Y = unique(X1[,c("id","time"), with=FALSE], by="id", fromLast=TRUE)
    X1[Y[time > 7], status := FALSE]
},
OP = {
    y <- X2[,.SD[.N],by=id]
    X2[y,status:=status & time > 7]
},
Floo0a = X3[,status := c(.SD[-.N, status], .SD[.N, status * time >7]), by=id],
Floo0b = X4[X4[,.N, by=id][,cumsum(N)], status := status * time >7],
tlm = X5[ X5[,.I==.I[which.max(time)], by=id]$V1 & time > 7, status := FALSE],
Symbolix=X6[ X6[order(time), .I[.N], by=id]$V1 , status := ifelse(time > 7, FALSE, TRUE)],
Frank1 = {
    y <- X7[, .SD[.N, .(time, status)], by=id][time > 7 & status]
    X7[y, status := FALSE]
},
Frank2 = {
    y <- X8[, .SD[.N], by=id][time > 7 & status]
    X8[y, status := FALSE]
}, times = 1, unit = "relative")
```

Result:

```
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
   unique   1.348592   1.348592   1.348592   1.348592   1.348592   1.348592     1
       OP  35.048724  35.048724  35.048724  35.048724  35.048724  35.048724     1
   Floo0a 416.175654 416.175654 416.175654 416.175654 416.175654 416.175654     1
   Floo0b   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000     1
      tlm   2.151996   2.151996   2.151996   2.151996   2.151996   2.151996     1
 Symbolix   1.770835   1.770835   1.770835   1.770835   1.770835   1.770835     1
   Frank1 404.045660 404.045660 404.045660 404.045660 404.045660 404.045660     1
   Frank2  36.603303  36.603303  36.603303  36.603303  36.603303  36.603303     1
```